# Кеширование результатов константного метода

Tags: c++

Есть константный метод класса, который часто вызывается. Решил кешировать его результаты, чтобы если параметры класса не изменились, выдавать кешированное значение, иначе заново считать. Однако это нарушает константность метода, хотя для пользователя класса ничего не меняется. Как лучше это сделать, чтобы и кешировать, и константность не терять? Может как-то изменить архитектура класса?

Вот как я себе это представляю:

```
class A {
    int cached_value;
    int parameter;
    bool is_value_cached = false;

public:
    void set_parameter(int x) {
        parameter = x;
        is_value_cached = false;
    }

    int foo() const { // const error
        if (!is_value_cached) {
            // ...compute value according to parameter...
            cached_value = 42; // assign value to cached_value
            is_value_cached = true;
        }

        return cached_value;
    }
};
```

Comment: https://habr.com/company/infopulse/blog/341264/

Comment: А зачем притворяться, что метод не изменяет состояние объекта, объявляя его c `const` квалификатором, если он может менять состояние объекта? Как альтернативу, можно попробовать написать внешний кешировщик, в котором будет что-то типа мапы parameter -> cached_value. Это кстати будет полезно когда у вас несколько экземпляров класса, или значения параметра в них могут повторяться.

Comment: @VTT он не изменяет интерфейс, о котором думает пользователь, а только какую-то скрытую деталь. Надо чтобы `const`-корректность сохранялась, ведь этот класс далее используется в константных методах и т.п.

Comment: "он не изменяет интерфейс" - какая-то непонятная фраза. Метод может менять состояние объекта или нет, видно это состояние пользователю или нет - совсем не важно.

Comment: @VTT: Видно ли это изменение пользователю не просто важно, а это с бльшим отрывом *самый важный* фактор в данном случае. "Состояние объекта" - понятие логического, а не физического уровня. "Состояние объекта" - это обычно именно и только то, что видно/доступно клиентскому коду. Создатель класса сам решает, что будет частью состояния, а что нет. В данном случае мы имеем как раз таки хрестоматийный пример ситуации, когда метод абсолютно *обязан* быть `const`, но при этом должен физически менять внутреннее содержимое объекта.

Comment: @AnT, в С++ очень сильно связаны "физическое" и "логическое" состояния. const является описанием интерфейса и сообщает пользователю, что данный метод следует const-семантике. Пользователь опрашивает в несколько потоков и получает падения (в лучшем случае) или рассогласование данных (что хуже, т.к. тяжело отлаживать). Всё-таки мутабл это ближе к костылю,причем к тому виду неявных костылей, которые вводят в заблуждение)

Comment: @steven, можно малой кровью переделать. `is_value_cached` - выносите в паблик геттер. И делаете метод вроде `recalc()` неконстантный и блокирующий объект. Дальше можно сделать класс-обертку, который будет вызывать сначала `is_value_cached` требуемого объекта, а потом в зависимости от состояния `recalc()` и `get_cached_value()`. Даже вроде всё неплохо заворачивается в шаблон :)

Comment: Дополнительно можно переложить вычисления на третью сторону, т.е. если у вас рассчитывается что-то в гетеере, то можно это делать в сеттере, каждый раз, когда меняется значение, а геттер оставить константным. Но это уже зависит от специфики проекта.

Comment: @goldstar_labs: В С++ понятия логической и физической константности не связаны никак. Это полностью вопрос вашего дизайна. У вас есть полная свобода в реализации вашей идеи "логической" константности, сколь угодно далеко оторванной от физической константности. Пример с потоками иллюстрирует лишь криворукость пользователя, который почему-то возомнил, что константность подразумевает многопоточную реентрабельность. Ничего подобного С++ константность не обещает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mutable` как раз для таких целей придумали.

Достаточно добавить его к объявлениям полей, которые хотите менять в константном методе:

```
mutable int cached_value;
mutable bool is_value_cached = false;
```

Comment: понял, так работает. А есть какие-нибудь побочные эффекты от такого объявления? `mutable` как-то по-другому хранятся, что их можно изменять?

Comment: @steven Нет, побочных эффектов нет. *"как-то по-другому хранятся, что их можно изменять?"* Если у вас в классе нет `mutable` полей, то константные глобальные (а может и еще какие-то) экземпляры класса компилятор может засунуть в память с защитой от записи. С `mutable` полями он больше не сможет так делать.

Comment: @steven Да, `mutable` порождает массу весьма неприятных побочных эффектов. Прежде всего `const` квалификатор в интерфейсе класса больше ничего не говорит о том, что метод не будет менять состояние класса. Как отмечено выше, компилятор не сможет размещать объекты в память только для чтения, однако ничего не мешает сделать это пользователю (true story 1: shared memory, процесс-читатель падает с ошибкой доступа при вызове const метода, начинается разбор полетов с выяснением, какой ***** запихнул в дебри класса mutable счетчик).

Comment: @steven Далее, если захочется вынести часть вычислений на этап компиляции, или какие-то шаблоны прикрутить, то выяснится, что `constexpr` и `mutable` не очень хорошо ладят (true story 2). Короче говоря, в С++ и так реализована слабая и неполная поддержка const-корректности, так что не надо отнимать у пользователей фактически единствное средство языка, которое хоть как-то позволяет судить об изменении состоянии объекта.

Comment: @VTT а как тогда кешировать или захватывать мьютексы в конст методах?

Comment: @VTT было бы здорово делать это без `mutable`, раз он такой плохой

Comment: @steven Никак. Если метод изменяет состояние объекта  - то я не объявляю его как `const`.

Comment: @VTT то есть если есть геттер в многопоточном приложении, где надо захватывать мьютекс, то геттер будет неконстантным у вас?

Comment: @steven Именно так.